# Mi bucle while se repite más veces

Tags: java, algoritmos

Este es codigo java, el es un ejercicio en el que se le solicite al usuario las calificaciones de los estudiantesde de un curso.El programa termina cuando ya no hay mas alumnos a los que poner nota o cuando ingresa una nota negativa. Al terminar,se debe mostrar el promedio, ademas de los que aprobaron y desaprobaron.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        int alumnos;
        int notas;
        int alumno = 1;
        int itAprobados = 0;
        int itDesaprobados = 0;
        boolean iteracionAlumnos = true;

        System.out.println("Número de alumnos");
        alumnos = teclado.nextInt();
        System.out.println("¿Cuantas notas son?");
        notas = teclado.nextInt();

        while (iteracionAlumnos) {
            float suma = 0;
            iteracionAlumnos = (alumno <= alumnos);
            System.out.println("Ingrese las calificaciones del alumno número " + alumno);

            int i = 1;
            boolean iteracionNotas = true;
            while (iteracionNotas) {
                iteracionNotas = (i < notas);
                System.out.println("Ingresa la nota número " + i + " : ");
                int nota = teclado.nextInt();
                if (nota < 0 || nota > 20) {
                    iteracionNotas = false;
                    iteracionAlumnos = false;
                } else {
                    suma += nota;
                    i++;
                }
            }

            if (iteracionAlumnos) {
                float promedio = (suma / notas);
                if (promedio > 11) {
                    itAprobados += 1;
                } else {
                    itDesaprobados += 1;
                }
                System.out.println("El promedio del alumno es: " + promedio);
            }

            alumno++;
        }
        System.out.println("Cantidad de aprobados es: " + itAprobados);
        System.out.println("Cantidad de desaprobados es: " + itDesaprobados);
    }
```

**El problema que tengo es que esta linea :**
`iteracionAlumnos = (alumno <= alumnos);`
**me provoca un exceso de 1. Pero cuando intento cambiar a :**
`iteracionAlumnos = (alumno < alumnos);`
el unico problema que tengo es cuando 'alumno' es igual 1 porque 'iteracionAlumnos' se vuelve false y para el la condicion if eso es malo.

**Al ejecutar el codigo teniendo** `iteracionAlumnos = (alumno <= alumnos);` **obtengo**:

```
Número de alumnos
2
¿Cuantas notas son?
2
Ingrese las calificaciones del alumno número 1
Ingresa la nota número 1 : 
14
Ingresa la nota número 2 : 
15
El promedio del alumno es: 14.5
Ingrese las calificaciones del alumno número 2
Ingresa la nota número 1 : 
14
Ingresa la nota número 2 : 
15
El promedio del alumno es: 14.5
Ingrese las calificaciones del alumno número 3
Ingresa la nota número 1 : 
6
Ingresa la nota número 2 : 
5
Cantidad de aprobados es: 2
Cantidad de desaprobados es: 0
```

Fijate que la cantidad de aprobados( o desaprobados) corresponde a la cantidad de alumnos.

**Y esto cuando cuando el codigo tiene `iteracionAlumnos = (alumno < alumnos);` :**

```
Número de alumnos
1
¿Cuantas notas son?
2
Ingrese las calificaciones del alumno número 1
Ingresa la nota número 1 : 
15
Ingresa la nota número 2 : 
16
Cantidad de aprobados es: 0
Cantidad de desaprobados es: 0
```

Y aqui la cantidad de aprobados y desaprobados es -1 , la verdad no entiendo.

Comment: solo esta desordenado tu while.. si al final aumentas alumno.. porque la comprobacion la haces al empezar la vuelta de nuevo, en lugar de en el punto siguiente a ese?????

Comment: @gbianchi como así , no logré entenderte del todo amigo, puedes detallarme mejor porfavor

Comment: Gracias ya entendí cual era el problema